# Use of fread() from data.table causes R session to abort

Tags: r, session, data.table, fread

I am working on a project for a MOOC, and was tinkering around with the `data.table` package in RStudio.  Use of the `fread()` function to import the data files initially worked fine:

```
fread("UCI HAR Dataset/features.txt")->features
fread("UCI HAR Dataset/test/y_test.txt")->ytest
```

However, when I tried to run the following line of code, I received a pop-up that said "R Session Aborted: R encountered a fatal error.  The session was terminated."

```
fread("UCI HAR Dataset/test/X_test.txt")->xtest
```

I don't understand what the problem is.  I checked the file names and paths to make sure I had correctly spelled and capitalized everything, and it all checks out.  The equivalent code using read.table() works fine and does not cause R to abort. I also tried renaming the file to "x_test.txt", but the same issue occurred.

According to `?fread`, only the function will only work with "regular delimited files." As far as I can tell, the file is a "regular delimited file", in that all rows have the same number of columns.  There are no cells containing "NA" when I use read.table instead; I checked using `anyNA()`.  Is there a quick way to determine whether a file is a delimited "regularly" or not?   Is there something else about the original file that could be causing the problem?

---

**UPDATE**

After further research and searching through the reported issues listed on the developer's github,  I think that my problem lies in having two white spaces at the beginning of each row, which is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22344161/fread-unable-to-read-csv-files-with-first-column-empty).  I am unsure why R aborted instead of giving me a warning. The latest development version of data.table (1.9.5) isn't causing the session to abort under the same conditions, though.

Comment: That is the sort of error that one should report to the package maintainer hopefully with a test case that reliably causes the abend. There is little chance that we can replicate your observations.

Comment: it is probably because of special characters `\r` or similar or nested quotations.  `fread` fails on things like that, open your document in emacs or a text editor where you can see the special characters

Answer (score 2):

Although I do believe you should have contacted the package maintainer first for any situation where the R session was aborted (and it was not due to your mucking with C-code), I can offer a strategy for your last request which is not really specific to `fread` but I've found useful with regular-reads(). I'm going to assume that this is a comma separated file but if it;'s whitespace separated you could change the `sep=","` to `sep=""`.

```
filcnts <- count.fields("UCI HAR Dataset/test/X_test.txt", sep=",")
table(filcnts)
```

That should be a single items table. If not, try switching parameters such as `quote`, `sep`, `blank.lines.skip`, or `comment.char`

Comment: Thanks for recommending that I contact the developer first.  Installing the in-development version of data.table() (as recommended on their bug report instructions) actually gave me a meaningful error message while using fread() instead of crashing the program.